# Saving variables inside node js modules

Tags: node.js, module

I have a node js module. What it does is, it takes in some data, process it and saves the results inside that module. I don't know how to save the results inside module.

I have tried saving variables directly but it does not work.

This is the module calc.js ..

```
module.exports.add = (number1, number2) => {
   sum = number1 + number2;
   return true;
}
```

Then inside my index.js

```
calc.add(5,10);
console.log(calc.sum);
```

How can I get calc.sum?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save variables inside a module like this. If you return the calculated value, it will be printed in the console.log(). Following is a working setup.

https://repl.it/repls/FluidHorizontalPasswords